# Wait for a event result in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, asynchronous

I'm using a bluetooth printer SDK,

which has a call back interface method to be trigger on search completed.

```kotlin
fun method1(){
    val callBack = HoinPrinterCallBack(callBack = fun (): Int{
             //Triggered after search completed
             return 0;
            })
    mHoinPrinter = HoinPrinter.getInstance(this, 1, callBack)
}
```

Callback interface implementation

```kotlin
typealias CallBack = () -> Int

class HoinPrinterCallBack () : PrinterCallback {

    override fun onEvent(p0: PrinterEvent?) {
        print(p0)
        if(p0?.event == Constant.EVENT_FIND_BT_DEVICE || p0?.event == Constant.EVENT_DISCOVERY_BT_FINISHED){
            callBack()
        }
        }
    }

}
```

I pass a callBack method to be triggered on search completed event in above code.

Then there is a separate method API for search of bluetooth device.

```kotlin
fun methhod2(){
    mHoinPrinter.startBtDiscovery();
}
```

My requirement is to wait for the completed event callback after `startBTDiscovery`. Any suggestions on how I can proceed further?

Comment: It looks like this callback will be called multiple times, so you can't wrap the API directly with a suspend function like is usually advised. Instead, maybe you can use your callback to push events to a `ShareFlow`, and then listen to the proper event when making the `startBtDiscovery()` call.

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey, I'm new to Kotlin. I'll check how I could use it. One more thing I forgot to mention I use it in flutter method channel.